# creating a library function with variable param name in PHP

Tags: php

I am sure this is obvious to most PHP programmers but I can't find much on the web. I am creating a library function and have a function (more complicated that what's below) and need to pass in a single variable. I can't guarantee that parameter will be called the same thing every time though. So I guess what I'm asking is how to grab the parameter (with multiple possible names) that is passed in and store it in a variable to be manipulated in the function. Here is an example:

```
function commentFormatTime(){
   $imported time = ?? //how do I grab what I am passing in?
   $replythen = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $importedTime)   
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any explanation if I misused or missing any terms here.

Comment: `function commentFormatTime($importedTime)` ?

Comment: I was under the impression it had to be named the same thing as the variable that was passed in when you called the function. guess that was a big misconception...

Comment: The answer from Mike expounds on my premise. If you want to make sure the variable doesn't give a warning if empty, you can use `function commentFormatTime($importedTime = false)` or similar (you would probably want to do an `if($importedTime != false) { do rest of code }`

Comment: Function arguments are identified by position rather than their name at call time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `$param = null` in your function ie:

```
function commentFormatTime($param = null){
   $imported time = $param; //how do I grab what I am passing in?
   $replythen = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $importedTime)   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a logical easier to understand way:

```
function commentFormatTime($incoming_variable){
   $importedTime = $incoming_variable;
   $replythen = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $importedTime);
}
```

Or for a faster way, use the incoming variable instead of making another one:

```
function commentFormatTime($importedTime){
   $replythen = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $importedTime);
}
```

And don't use spaces in variable names.

Comment: My guess would be that `$imported time` just was meant to demonstrate what he would like to do.